# Why is does this area of the mesh look weird?

Tags: modeling, vertices, faces

I have been curious as to why this specific area of the head mesh (corner of the mouth) look weird even though I made sure that there are no vertex crossing each other. I tried to move around each vertex, but the weird line was still visible even though I move the vertexes. What can I do to fix it? [image]

[image]

Comment: It might be that the two loop cuts in the upper lip don't continue around under the lower lip.

Comment: I just added the edges to the two loop cuts using the multi-cut tool and the weird line only just worsened. So that might not be it.

Comment: It would help if you uploaded your .blend file here http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ Then copy the resulting link and using The "edit" function of you original post "paste" the link in.

Comment: Sorry I forgot the link, I thought it was directly sent to this post.

Comment: The blend file is in your post :) Now I think it might be because there is a face that is made up of 5 vertices. It should be 4.

Comment: Ohh, that helped a lot. When I read your statement about 5 vertices, I was thinking about it and found the big face that appears to have 5 vertices. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62104/discussion-between-shiningluna-and-dontwalk).

Comment: I made a quick work around (It's not exactly correct). Also, I deleted the inside of the mouth to make my quick fix easier for me. You can rebuild that easily. Here's the .blend [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3522" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3522/)